# Bind a SortedList to ListBox WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, listbox, sortedlist

I'm converting an older .NET WinForms app to WPF.  It uses a SortedList:

```
Dim MyCol as New System.Collections.SortedList(New CaseInsensitiveComparer)
```

It fills a ListBox in the form by iterating the list, i.e. no data binding.

```
For Each p In MyCol.Values
    lstBox.Items.Add(p.Name, False)
Next
```

It's nice because the items appear in the list sorted.  Also, because it contains Key,Value pairs, you can instantly get a desired object from the list, or see if it is in the list at all:

```
If MyCol.Contains("the key") ...

myObject = MyCol("the key")
Debug.Print(myObject.Name)
```

I do this a LOT in the app, so the 'random access' nature of the SortedList is very important for performance.

So, fast forward to WPF, I need to bind my ListBox to MyCol, but would like to keep it as a SortedList, if possible.  How can I bind it?

**Edit**: To clarify further, I am trying to do it right and want to use MVVM.  And ideally I'd bind an ObservableCollection(of myClass) to the ListBox, and use Linq to sort and to query for a particular item.  But then I've lost the 'random access' that I had with the SortedList, and I fear this would be a significant performance hit.  But I haven't been able to figure out how to convert the SortedList to an ObservableCollection (I'm good, but not super-advanced), so I posted this question to explore if it's possible to stick with the SortedList first, before abandoning it for something else.

**What I ended up doing**, at least for starters:

In my ViewModel, I have a dependency property of type System.Collections.ICollection.  Let's call it MyColProperty.

Once MyCol is populated, I assign it to the property like this.  (SortedList.Values is of type System.Collections.ICollection).

```
MyColProperty = MyCol.Values
```

In the XAML, the ListBox binds to it like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyColProperty}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ListBox>
```

And that works to display the Name property of my objects in the MyCol SortedList.  So it's sort-of MVVM, though it's not an observable collection.  I'll have to see how far I can take it with that short-coming, and then make a decision whether to switch to a true ObservableCollection, or if this will do.

Thanks very much, and hope it helps someone who comes across it.
Sandra

Comment: possible duplicate of [CollectionViewSource Use Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124894/collectionviewsource-use-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way would be to simply set the SortedList as ItemsSource for the WPF ListBox and use the Name Property as DisplayMemberPath.

```
lstBox.ItemsSource = MyCol;
lstBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

nervertheless you should also look into MVVM and Binding when doing WPF now :)

Comment: Ah yes, MVVM is exactly what I'm trying to move to - sorry I didn't state it clearly in my question.  I'll edit.

Comment: You made me realize I may be able to bind to MyCol directly. I'll edit my question to include what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Make your collection MyCol as a collection of key and value, maybe something like,

```
new List<tuple<string,string>>()
```

Then bind your listBox to this collection with DisplayMemberPath as Item2 and use Item one as your key for searching etc.

Also you can use LINQ to sort your list,

```
myCol.OrderBy(p => p.Item2)
```

Comment: Thanks, though for me, changing away from SortedList is what I'm hoping to avoid, at least for this question.  I edited my question to clarify the goal.